# FATAL EXCEPTION main Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, preferences, fatal-error

I am currently working on an Android app. When I click Menu, the Menu shows up, but then if you choose "Preferences" it crashes. If you click "New" it works fine. I don't know what is going on. I am new to Android App development and the eclipse IDE, so anything helps. Here is the LogCat:

```html
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: r
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1420)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1357)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1463)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1102)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1063)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1032)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2104)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2078)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.preference.ListPreference.getSummary(ListPreference.java:152)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.preference.Preference.onBindView(Preference.java:500)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:450)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1949)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1139)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:956)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:521)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1890)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:884)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2003)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-14 12:14:44.665: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the method that is called at the time of the crash:

```
/** when menu button option selected */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_options:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, WordSearchPreferences.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_new:
        control.newWordSearch();
        return true;
    }return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the preferences.xml that is used for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference android:key="@string/prefs_size"
    android:title="@string/size" android:defaultValue="10"
    android:summary="@string/prefs_size_summary"
    android:entryValues="@array/sizes_list_values"
    android:entries="@array/sizes_list_labels" />
<ListPreference android:key="@string/prefs_category"
    android:title="@string/category" android:defaultValue="@string/RANDOM"
    android:summary="@string/prefs_category_summary"
    android:entryValues="@array/categories_list_values"
    android:entries="@array/categories_list_labels" />
<ListPreference android:key="@string/prefs_touch_mode"
    android:title="@string/input_type" android:defaultValue="@string/DRAG"
    android:summary="@string/prefs_touch_mode_summary"
    android:entryValues="@array/touch_mode_list_values"
    android:entries="@array/touch_mode_list_labels" />
<ListPreference android:key="@string/PREFS_THEME"
    android:title="@string/THEME" android:defaultValue="@string/THEME_ORIGINAL"
    android:summary="@string/PREFS_THEME_SUMMARY"
    android:entryValues="@array/THEME_VALUES"
    android:entries="@array/THEME_LABELS" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Please post the preference XML you are using, at least the part for the `ListPreference` that is crashing.

Comment: share OnItemSelected() code for the item where app crashed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListPreference` uses `String.format()` to generate the summary for the preference, so you can blend in data from the preference itself via `%s`. You appear to be using `%` or something in the description that is confusing `String.format()`. Make sure `@string/prefs_size_summary` and the others have values that will behave properly with `String.format()`.

Also, usually you don't use string resources for `android:key`, because you are not going to be translating your preference keys. Only use string resources for things that will actually be translated.

Comment: what do you mean by the description?

Comment: @comead: The strings referenced by your `android:summary` cannot have stuff in them that look like they should be replaced by `String.format()`.

Comment: ACTUALLY, its not completely fixed.. when i remove that percent, i use it as a placeholder for a variable settings. %replaceme i cant take it out, because it is used to stay read what is the current settting

Comment: @comead: If you want to have the current value displayed in the summary, try using `%s`, not `%replaceme`. `%replaceme` is not valid syntax for `String.format()`.

Comment: that works! thank you so much!!! i'm new to android (and this is actually someone else's app, that I am amending). I am also new to StackOverflow, is there anything I can do to help you on here? like "Thanks" button or anything?

Comment: @comead: You will see an outline of a checkmark to the left of my answer. Checking that indicates that you "accept" the answer, indicating that if others search StackOverflow and find your question, this answer solved your problem.