# How to escape '%' in android preferences

Tags: android, xml, string, android-preferences

I have read this thread [FATAL EXCEPTION main Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125524/fatal-exception-main-android-app) and it is very helpful.

And YES this works nice

```
<string formatted="false">some text and % in the text</string>
```

so if someone uses xml the formatted="false" is the solution.

But I have problem in the code

```
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("my_key").setSummary("some text and % in the text"));
```

and this trows an exception, does anybody knows how can I escape the % ?

so when the String.format() is called the % will be treated like '%' and not like an special character

Thanks

Comment: What about escaping it in Unicode values? \u0025 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just double it up!  Instead of using one percent, use two.  Like so.

```
setSummary("some text and %% in the text")
```

Comment: this works but not complicatedly, if someone have this kind of problem need to check the build version and if is less then 14 (ice-cream-sandwich) then use "%" if is ice cream or something after ice-cream then use "%%" , I hope this will help to someone

Comment: One small add. If you need value from <string-array to contain "%" and alongside with summary with such value, than simple doubling wont help. For for <string-array linked in in ListView preference as a android:entries - use "%", than replace "%" programmatically with "%%" and use it in setSummary(CharSequence summary). Reason is that "%%" in ListVIew entries does not work as escape charater, unlike in setSummary...